# Google Sheets API extreme latency

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am experiencing a median latency of over 40s on `google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues` function. I am reading single sheet of data with 250,000 cells (14 cols x 18,000 rows). I am well under the rate limits rarely doing more than a single call in 100s and more than 200 a day.

When downloaded as CSV, the file size is ~3MB (440KB zipped).

Now, I understand that reading 3MB of data might not be instant, but 40s is order of magnitude slower than I would expect. Especially given that simple manual download as CSV takes ~1s to complete.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get data through API faster?

Example of the code I am using

```js
  async function load(id, range) {
    await sheetsApi.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: id,
      range,
      valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE',
    })
  }

  await Promise.all([
    load(id1, 'Big'), // big 250k cells sheet
    load(id1, 'Small'), // small 1000 cells sheet
    load(id2, 'Big'), // another big 250k cells sheet
  ])
```

Playing further with profiling I am seeing following data:

```
[0] Loading id2:Big took 1644ms.    // Notice how this big sheet loaded really fast.
[0] Loading id1:Small took 26345ms. // Notice that this small sheet took 26 seconds.
[0] Loading id1:Big took 27274ms.
[0] Loading id1:Small took 859ms.
[0] Loading id2:Big took 1493ms.
[0] Loading id1:Big took 1610ms.
[0] Loading id1:Small took 865ms.
[0] Loading id2:Big took 1689ms.
[0] Loading id1:Big took 1835ms.
```

So it seems like some kind of undisclosed rate limiting or whatever. Sometimes it's really fast, sometimes it's extremely slow.

Comment: In your script, it seems that 3 API calls are done by the method of spreadsheets.values.get, so how about doing them by one API call using the method of spreadsheets.values.batchGet?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for suggestion, it's only 2 API calls (the third is to different spreadsheet). Frankly, it's a natural optimisation, but I don't really see it having big impact. The second sheet is pretty small.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's feasible for your situation, could you download the entire sheet as a CSV file, or 3 of them, 1 per sheet.  It's probably a lot slower for the API to filter the data rows individually out into API call results and serialize them, rather than export the whole sheet(s) to a file.

Comment: Is there a way to download sheet to CSV using API?

Comment: @SamuelHapak I don't think so, I think you need to use the Google Drive API.